# Can I get an anonymous class from a builder?

Tags: java, builder-pattern

I know I can create an anonymous class when manually creating an instance of it like this:

```
ClassName c = new ClassName() {
    public void overridenMethod() { method body }
}
```

Some classes, however, use builder pattern to create a new instance. My question is whether there is a trick that would allow me to create an anonymous class using the builder provided by its superclass.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstanding question, but you can return instance of anonymous class as long as that anon class implements/extends type specified as return type of your `ResultType builder.build()`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Do you suggest I modify the builder? I cannot. I was looking for something similar to my code snippet above. Like `builder.build() {overridenMethod() { method body }}`. I considered builder pattern to be a possible full alternative to standard constructors, but apparently it is not so.

Comment: ah, understood now. In this case dasblinkenlight's answer is the way.

Answer (score 4):

No, or at least not directly: in Java you cannot inherit from an instance; you need to inherit from a class.

However, you can build an anonymous class *wrapping* an instance returned from the builder. You can call methods on the wrapped instance as you see fit, while overriding the ones that you need to override.

```
final ClassName wrapped = builder.buildClassName();
ClassName c = new ClassName() {
    public void passedThroughMethod1() { wrapped.passedThroughMethod1() }
    public void overridenMethod() { method body }
    public void passedThroughMethod2() { wrapped.passedThroughMethod2() }
};
```

At this point, `c` behaves just like the `wrapped` instance, except for the `overridenMethod`. An unfortunate consequence is that you cannot access protected members of the `wrapped`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question right, you want the builder to return an instance of the anonymous type. If that is the case, I would add a `create` method in the base class which the builder invokes to create the new instance. In you derived class override `create` to return an instance of the anonymous class. This assumes that the builder has access to an instance of the base class. Another mechanism is to provide a `Supplier` to the builder.

[Supplier](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Supplier.html)